# Visualise returns of n-asset portfolio as 2D plot, like heatmap?

Tags: portfolio-optimization, portfolio, visualization

It's possible to visualise both **asset allocations and returns** of 2-assets portfolio as 2D heatmap.

Like in image below, the visualisation of $[Gold, Silver]$ portfolio with restriction $Gold + Silver = 1$. Color and size of circle represent the returns for given asset allocation.

[image]

What are the ways to somehow represent 5-asset (and in general N-assets) portfolio as 2D plot? Some dimensionality reduction technics, clustering similar portfolios or other tricks?

It should somehow show or hint both - **asset allocation and returns**.

Why - to better understand what's going on. Visually access the performance how it changes with asset allocation changes, how smooth the surface is, if there's no jumps, get some insights from it, if it looks reasonable or not, etc.

Comment: Your question (and objective) isn't really clear.  'Asset fraction' isn't a commonly used term, please define it.  Otherwise, please elaborate on the dimensions you're attempting to represent in 2-D.  If you haven't, Hans Rosling's TED talk is legend, definitely instructive and potentially useful here

Comment: @Chris I updated the question and added example plot, please check it out. I meant asset allocation, not fractions. Yes, I remember his talk, maybe a good option would be to make this graph interactive or represent it as animation to visualise more dimensions.

Comment: To take this where it seems you're trying to go (ie, how to allocate across 5 assets to 'maximize' return), there isn't a good way to represent that a la an efficient frontier in 2-D since your trade offs are in 5-D.  Dimensionality reduction won't be useful because your resulting vectors aren't investible, they're some combination of your assets which doesn't help.  I would consider plotting the interplay between 2 assets, holding allocation to others fixed to get a sense for partial sensitivities.  A correlation matrix can also be instructive and lends itself to N assets.